# Substring after two character occurrences

Tags: batch, batch-file, window

I want to select a specific part of a string that could be like this:

`<text1>_<text2>_V1_0_<text3>`

I've tried something like this:

`set current_folder_path=%cd% set version=!current_folder_path:~18,6!`

But it only select a fixed string, it is not dynamic.
All texts can be have a variable length.

How can I select "V1_0" after two occurrences of "_" ?

Comment: You have posted batch as tag in this question. Can you provide your script by editing your question, so we can see what you already tried?

Comment: Yes. let's see your script. It will have `FOR /F` and `tokens` and `delims` I expect.

Comment: Your example has `V1_0` and you ask to select `V_1_0`? Please fix your post and add more information about what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it maybe something like this:

```
@echo off

IF /i Exist "%~1" (set Folder=%~1) else (set /p "Folder=Please Specify a Folder: ")

set Folder=%Folder:"=%
For /f "tokens=3-4 delims=_" %%a in ("%Folder%") do set Version=%%a_%%b
echo The Current Version is %Version%
echo.
pause
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ricardo, it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry if it's a "simple" question, I'm a newbie in batch file. :-)